# MySQL forming JSON_OBJECT, specify absence on NULL - is it possible?

Tags: mysql, json, null

I am converting some of my MySQL.
I am using `JSON_OBJECT` and `JSON_OBJECTAGG` to form the JSON documents.
The problem is that I've got many NULL fields, in which case I don't want MySQL to add NULL field to JSON structure. I want this field to be not present.

Is it possible with any version of MySQL?

Scanning the internet, I've found there is something like that in Oracle DB:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370

There is `ABSENT ON NULL` clause.

Answer (score 9):

I just got the same question. Here is how I solved it :

```
select ...,  
JSON_REMOVE(JSON_OBJECTAGG(IFNULL(column_holding_property_name, 'null__'), column_holding_property_value), '$.null__') as result_column_name  
from ... group by ...;
```

It replaces the null keys with `'null__'`, then removes them from the final object. So no post-processing is needed.
The `JSON_REMOVE` converts `{"null__":1,"b":2}` into `{"b":2}` and also `{"null__":1}` into `{}`, so the final result is always an object.
BTW, I used `'null__'` because I know that `column_holding_property_value` will never contain that value.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:

Here's a way to deal with this in mysql:

```
JSON_OBJECTAGG(IFNULL(key, ''), value)
```

The null field will get remapped to '', preventing the SQL error. Then when you're parsing the result you can filter out the empty ''.

This solution kind of depends on being able to let the caller do post-query filtering.

Solution 2:

Another way to get rid of these null values, whether they're in the key or value of the object, is to just add a where clause. For example:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(color, red) 
FROM ( SELECT 'color', 'red' UNION select 'color2', 'blue' UNION select 'color3', null ) AS x
WHERE red IS NOT NULL
```

Note that this where thing might not help you if your nulls are coming from a left join, and you still need the null fields to be present for other purposes.

If neither of these two solutions work, then sorry, I'm out of ideas for you!

Comment: How does is solve the problem? This prevents `JSON_OBJECTAGG` from failing if you provide NULL as a key.

Check this:
select json_objectagg(color, red) from (
 select 'color', 'red'
    union
 select 'color2', 'blue'
    union
 select 'color3', null   
) s;

The idea is to filter out `color3` from the results, since its null.

Comment: How about just adding a where clause? See my update.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I was specifically looking for `ABSENT ON NULL` equivalent. Your solution 2 does seem to work OK for my example however it doesn't address the problem in question where I form JSON object using JSON_OBJECT. 
The example in my comment I've shown with `color` key and `colorValue` is simple, perhaps not accurate enough.
In my question, the `colorValue` equivalent is actually the object formed by JSON_OBJECT which has some keys inside that needs to be filtered out when NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following could be a work around for the absence of `ABSENT ON NULL`:

Splitting

```
JSON_OBJECT( key1, value1, key2, value2, ..., keyX, valueX )
```

into multiple `JSON_OBJECT()` functions and merging them conditionally with `JSON_MERGE_PATCH()`:

```
JSON_MERGE_PATCH( IF( value1 is null, "{}", JSON_OBJECT( key1, value1 ) ), 
                  IF( value2 is null, "{}", JSON_OBJECT( key2, value2 ) ), 
                  ..., 
                  IF( valueX is null, "{}", JSON_OBJECT( keyX, valueX ) )
                )
```

The query example:

```
SELECT 
     JSON_OBJECT( 'value', q.SEQ,
                  'isEven', q.IS_EVEN,
                  'isMultipleOfThree', q.IS_MULTIPLE_OF_3
                ) AS result
    FROM ( SELECT 
                SEQ, 
                NULLIF( SEQ MOD 2 = 0, FALSE ) AS IS_EVEN, 
                NULLIF( SEQ MOD 3 = 0, FALSE ) AS IS_MULTIPLE_OF_3
           FROM SEQ_1_TO_6 ) AS q
```

when transformed to

```
SELECT 
     JSON_MERGE_PATCH( JSON_OBJECT( 'value', q.SEQ ),
                       IF( q.IS_EVEN IS NULL, "{}", JSON_OBJECT( 'isEven', q.IS_EVEN ) ),
                       IF( q.IS_EVEN IS NULL, "{}", JSON_OBJECT( 'isMultipleOfThree', q.IS_MULTIPLE_OF_3 ) )
                     ) AS result
FROM ( SELECT 
            SEQ, 
            NULLIF( SEQ MOD 2 = 0, FALSE ) AS IS_EVEN, 
            NULLIF( SEQ MOD 3 = 0, FALSE ) AS IS_MULTIPLE_OF_3
       FROM SEQ_1_TO_6 ) AS q
```

will only show those attributes, which are not null.